# Rest Framework serializers, forbid users to change others password

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm creating a simple web app and I cannot find any way to forbid other users from changing your password. This is minimal code:

```
# serializers.py
from rest_framework import serializers

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def create(self, validated_data):
        # have to use custom create method because default method calls `User.objects.create()` which doesn't take care of password hashing and other important stuff 
        return User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email', 'password')
        read_only_fields = ('id', 'username')

        # password is set to write_only because I don't want to send it to anybode (even though it's just a hash)
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

# views.py
from .serializers import UserSerializer
from rest_framework import generics
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserDetails(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):

    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

I could take care of this myself by using `APIView`.

```
# views.py
from .serializers import UserSerializer
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserDetails(APIView):
    def put(self, request, format=None):

        serialized = UserSerializer(data=request.DATA)
        if not serialized.is_valid():
            return # probably HTTP 400 Error code
        if request.user.id != serialized.data['id']:
            # this if is what I'm trying to achieve
            return # probably HTTP 403 Error code
        user = User.objects.update(
            id=serialized.data['id'],
            email=serialized.data['email']
        )
        if 'password' in request.DATA:
            user.set_password(request.DATA['password'])
        return # probably HTTP 200 Error code
```

Unfortunately, that would have caused that scheme generated by `rest_framework.schemas.get_schema_view` would be incomplete. And I use for communication CoreAPI (which cannot communicate with something that is not described in the scheme) so I cannot do that. I haven't found anything in the official documentation.
This seems to be a too basic problem that has a super easy solution that I missed. Thanks for any ideas or places where to look.

PS: I'm using django2.1 with python3.6

Edit: osobacho's solutions is clean and works like charm. Anyway I also need to allow modifications (let's say of TODO-list) only to creator of that todo list. Thought that solution for password problem would be applicable but it's not.

Comment: The problem looks like an authentication problem. use this in your class before the definition of your function`permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)` and import IsAuthenticated `from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated`

Comment: Let's imagine we have 2 users Bob and Rick. Rick is authenticated but he is still able to change Bob's password - that is the problem I'm trying to solve. I'm looking for some kind of custom `permission_class`. Anyway thanks for replying.

Comment: I see the point, but both of them should have some session to keep their datas thus We can verify their datas. If Rick is authenticated then change his password or can see bob's password which is explained and exampled in the [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#examples)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the user in the request. That way each user will only be able to  change their own password.

```
class UserDetails(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user
```

For your second question take a look at django_restframework http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/ permissions here is an example:

```
class IsOwnerOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
"""
Object-level permission to only allow owners of an object to edit it.
Assumes the model instance has an `owner` attribute.
"""

def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
    # Read permissions are allowed to any request,
    # so we'll always allow GET, HEAD or OPTIONS requests.
    if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
        return True

    # Instance must have an attribute named `owner`.
    return obj.owner == request.user
```

then you need to add to your view:

```
 permission_classes = (IsOwnerOrReadOnly,)
```

hope it helps

Comment: I thought it were an authentication problem sorry :/

Comment: Hey, thanks for so clean and nice solution. I've updated the question a little bit. If you could help with the new one too I would be really happy. Thanks

Comment: No problem. I've updated my question. Take a look http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Nice answer. @jan you cannot change a question after an answer has been given. if the answer addressed the original question, you need to accept it and post a new one

Comment: Thanks, ocobacho - that is exactly what I was looking for. And I'm sorry @e4c5 for changing the answer - will create a new one next time. Thanks for the suggestion.